# Why won't vavr's Function1 accepting Seq<Parent> class accept Seq<Child>?

Tags: java, inheritance, functional-programming, vavr

I'm using Java with vavr and I have a Function1 that accepts a `Seq<Parent>` and returns a `String`. Why won't that class accept `Seq<Child>`? It seems like something with contravariance/covariance/invariance, but I am having trouble working through why it won't compile. Here is my code:

```
interface Bar {
    String getFoo();
}   

class Foo implements Bar {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public Foo(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}


class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function1<Seq<Bar>, String> myFunction = (it) -> "foo";
        Foo obj = new Foo("foo", "bar");
        Foo obj1 = new Foo("hello", "world");
        Seq<Foo> list = List.of(obj, obj1);
        String result = myFunction.apply(list); // IntelliJ says this line is incorrect
    }
}
```

Instead, I get the error (from IntelliJ):

```
    apply (io.vavr.collection.Seq<Bar>) in Function1 cannot be applied to (io.vavr.collection.Seq<Foo>).
```

This simple example seems like it should work just fine. What am I missing and why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. This can be boiled down to how Vavr handles variance with the Seq interface.

`Seq`s in Scala are covariant, meaning `Seq<Child>` is treated like a subclass of `Seq<Parent>`. Thus, the above problem when translated into Scala works.

```
class Bar {}
class Foo extends Bar

val foos: Seq[Foo] = Seq(new Foo, new Foo, new Foo);
val bars: Seq[Bar] = foos;
```

However, it seems the vavr's `Seq` interface is invariant, meaning `Seq<Parent>` and `Seq<Child>` are treated as separate classes. Vavr's `Seq` has a method called `narrow()` to make these upcasts work properly. That is how to solve the problem above.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function1<Seq<Bar>, String> myFunction = (it) -> "foo";
        Foo obj = new Foo("foo", "bar");
        Foo obj1 = new Foo("hello", "world");
        Seq<Foo> list = List.of(obj, obj1);
        String result = myFunction.apply(Seq.narrow(list));
```

Not sure why Vavr is designed this way.

Comment: Actually, its not Vavr that treats these as invariant, but Java.